# What is the use case of "inserting" class inside another class via prototype in javascript?

Tags: javascript, oop, prototype

Having this example:

```
class A {
  fooA() {
    console.log("fooA");
  }

  printFooBFromA() {
    const b = new this.B();
    b.fooB();
  }
}

class B {
  fooB() {
    console.log("fooB");
  }
}

A.prototype.B = B;

const a = new A();
a.printFooBFromA();
```

What is the use case of such scenario? Why would one want to insert another class retrospectively?

Comment: Did you encounter this in real code? Then that's your use case right there.

Comment: @Thomas I did, but I didn't really understand that. So another example would help better.

Comment: There might be a use case (reason) but no justification for the provided code. It's just an utterly wrong choice of tools and techniques. If one only knew the actual goal (precise requirements), one had the chance of cleaning this mess up.